# How do I get access to system specs via the Windows API?

Tags: c++, winapi

How do I access information about the computer's specifications from the Windows API? Do I need to look in the registry, if so where? Some key information I would like my programs to have access to are the graphics card model and specs, supported versions of OpenGL and DirectX, supported screen resolutions, CPU information, total/available disk space, and RAM information, among others. What types of efficient methods can I use to access this information in Win32?

Advice is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of this info, and much more, is exposed in Windows through WMI (Windows Management Instrumentation).  A good starting point to discover queries and try them out on your machine is the [WMI Code Creator tool](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=8572).  It generates code too but not C++ code.  That's fairly ugly but boilerplate, [look here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394558%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for code samples.  The set of standard Win32 WMI classes is [documented here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394554%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).