# Retrieve device model name using C++ on windows desktop

Tags: c++, windows

I would like to know how can I retrieve the device model using c++. For Instance, If I have a dell laptop to retrieve something like "studio 1534" or similar.

Comment: take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8369751/how-do-i-get-access-to-system-specs-via-the-windows-api

Comment: This requires Wbemidl.h and it requeres windows vista or higher, there is something for XP as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've ended implementing this code:

```
    // Retrieve the device model from the Registry
    HKEY hKey;
    char buf[255] = { 0 };
    DWORD dwType = 0;
    DWORD dwBufSize = sizeof(buf);
    try
    {
        if (RegOpenKey(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, TEXT("HARDWARE\\DESCRIPTION\\System\\BIOS"), &hKey) == ERROR_SUCCESS)
        {
            dwType = REG_SZ;
            if (RegQueryValueEx(hKey, TEXT("SystemProductName"), NULL, NULL, (LPBYTE)buf, &dwBufSize) == ERROR_SUCCESS)
            {
                setDeviceModel(String(buf));
            }
            RegCloseKey(hKey);
        }
    }
    catch (...) {}
```