# How to know the compute capability of my Nvidia Card in C/C++?

Tags: c++, c, cuda, gpu, nvidia

Many framework require that your nvidia graphic card has a specific compute capability version.

I am developing a C++ application that uses Cuda. I should get this information by code. so that I can assign the needed framework for each graphic compute capability.
How to know the compute capability of my nvidia graphic in C/C++?

Comment: go to nvidia.com, look up your gpu, find its specifications, read.

Comment: is it not possible via nvidia  executables?

Comment: I reedited the question to be more specific.

Comment: It would help if you specified what you mean by "compute possibility."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the [CUDA Runtime API](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/group__CUDART__DEVICE.html#group__CUDART__DEVICE_1g1bf9d625a931d657e08db2b4391170f0)

```
__host__ ​cudaError_t cudaGetDeviceProperties ( cudaDeviceProp* prop, int  device )
Returns information about the compute-device.
```

Alternatively, you could use `cudaDeviceGetAttribute` to get the specific properties you want.

precisely:
Returns in *prop the properties of device dev. The cudaDeviceProp structure is defined as:

```
‎    struct cudaDeviceProp {
              .... 
              int major;
              int minor;
              .....
   }
```

major, minor are the major and minor revision numbers defining the device's compute capability.

Comment: Thanks, +1. I reedited the response to be more precise for other readers.

Answer (score 0):

If you right click the nvidia icon on the bottom right of your screen then go to Nvidia control panel, a window will open then you can check all of the specs under "System Information" it's in the bottom left of the window .

Comment: Thanks a lot, +1. But I want it in C/C++.

Comment: Sorry I just saw the edit, you are looking for a way to use the windows API to access the system specs, or maybe take a look at amp(accelerated massive parallelism) try this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8369751/how-do-i-get-access-to-system-specs-via-the-windows-api